# What is the difference between $1 - p^k$ and $(1-p)^k$?

Tags: probability

Let $p$ be the probability that an event happens, then $1-p$ is the probability of that event **not** happening. The probability of that event happening $k$ times (in a row), i.e. rolling the same number for $k$ dice rolls, or landing heads $k$ times (in a row), is $p^k$ and similarly, the probability of not doing so is $(1-p)^k$.

If we argue that the probability of an event **not** happening is $1-$ that probability, why isn't the probability of **not** $p^k$ not equal to $1-p^k$?

Is it, that $1-p^k$ is the probability of $E$ "not happening $k$ times", e.g. $k-1$ times or less and $(1-p)^k$ $E$ not happening **exactly $k$ times**?

Comment: Make your title more explicit please.

Comment: _The probability of not $p^k$_ doesn't have a meaning: $p^k$ isn't an event, so it doesn't have a probability.

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability of event $A$ then $1-p$ is the probability of $A^\prime$. Now probability of observing consecutive $A$ k times would be $p^k$. Probability of not observing consecutive $A$ which is ($1-p^k$) is not the same as observing $A^\prime$ consecutive k times ($(1-p)^k$). It's like observing 2 consecutive tails (failure) is not the same as not observing 2 consecutive heads (success).

Answer (score 4):

If you have two events, E occurring with probability $p$, and the complementary event NE occurring with probability $1 - p$, then

- $p^k$ is the probability that E occurs $k$ times in a row.
- $(1 - p)^k$ is the probability that NE occurs $k$ times in a row.
- $1 - p^k$ is the probability that "E occurs $k$ times in a row" does *not* happen.  This is *not* the same event as "NE occurs $k$ times in a row", it *is* the same as "NE occurs at least once in $k$ consecutive trials".
- $1 - (1 - p)^k$ is the probability that the event "NE occurs $k$ times in a row" does *not* happen.  This is *not* the same as "E occurs $k$ times in a  row", it *is* the same as "E occurs at least once in $k$ consecutive trials".

To put this in the context of a simple example, the events referenced above can be specialized to the following in the case of a coin flip

- Heads is flipped $k$ times in a row.
- Tails is flipped $k$ times in a row.
- "Heads is flipped $k$ times in a row" does not happen $\Leftrightarrow$ Tails is flipped at least once.
- "Tails is flipped $k$ times in a row" does not happen $\Leftrightarrow$ Heads is flipped at least once.

English can be difficult and squeamish when you attempt to use it precisely.  The phrase "Heads is not flipped $k$ times in a row" is ambiguous, so I prefer to avoid it.

Here's another example of the ambiguity of language: another answer to the question in your title, if taken literally, is

$$(1 - p)^k - (1 - p^k) = \sum_{i = 0}^k (-1)^i {n \choose i} p^i - 1 + p^k = ((-1)^k - 1)p^k + \sum_{i = 1}^k {n \choose i} p^i $$

which I don't believe was what you were after.

Comment: +1, it would probably be easier for people to follow if you illustrated this with a simple example, say a short series of coin tosses.

Comment: @gung Like that?

Comment: I mean, to illustrate '... the probability that "E occurs k times in a row" does not happen. This is not the same event as "NE occurs k times in a row"...', eg, you could have T T H T means that you didn't get 4 Hs, but you didn't get 4 Ts either, or something like that. I dunno, it's just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is a probable event in a trial with constant probability of appearing  $p$, and we have a series of $k$ independent trials, then

$p^k$ is the probability that $E$ will happen in all the trials

$(1-p)^k$ is the probability that $E$ will not appear *at all* in *any* of the $k$ trials

$1-p^k$ is the probability that $E$ will not appear *in all* the trials - but it may appear in $1,...,k-1$ of them.

Realize that you have *two* different levels of "events, trials and probabilities" here : Looking at the whole $k$-trials setup, *there is no event $E$*: instead the events here are ordered sets of cardinality $k$, like $\{E,E,...,E\}$ (that has probability $p^k$),
$\{E^c,E^c,...,E^c\}$ (that has probability $(1-p)^k$ or
$\{E^c,E,...,E\}$ (that has probability $(1-p)p^{k-1}$etc.

So

$$1-p^k = 1- \text{Prob}(\{E,E,...,E\}) \neq \text{Prob}(\{E^c,E^c,...,E^c\}) = (1-p)^k$$

evidently, since there are many more possible events here than just $\{E,E,...,E\}$ and $\{E^c,E^c,...,E^c\}$.