# Probability that side k does not occur in a die

Tags: probability, self-study, dice

If there is a die with n sides (1,2,..k,..n) and it is rolled n times. What is the probability of the side labeled 'k', not occurring in n rolls?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: [(n-1)/n]$^n$ since (n-1)/n is the probability that a specific side will not occur on any given roll and the rolls are assumed to be independent.

Comment: @jbowman I'll make sure next time.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I got the same till (n-1)/n. But, I do not get why there is a power of n on it?

Comment: It has to happen n consecutive times.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209104/what-is-the-difference-between-1-pk-and-1-pk and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88980/why-on-average-does-each-bootstrap-sample-contain-roughly-two-thirds-of-observat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one roll:

$\text{P}(\text{side = }k)=\frac{1}{n}$

$\text{P}(\text{side $\neq$ }k)=1 - \frac{1}{n}$

In $n$ rolls:

$\text{P}(\text{side $\neq$ }k \text{ in n rolls})=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Comment: I have a follow up question, my homework says that you need to evaluate this expression for an increasing sequence of values. I don't need the answer for it, rather I just want to know what does the question mean/context of it is. It'd be great if you could use a different example to help explain this. Thanks!

Comment: I think that means that you should evaluate this expression for n=1, n=2, n=3, and so on.